# 3-Coloring Graph problem

Tags: np-complete, np, colorings

Can we prove that the 3 coloring graph problem (where no two adjacent nodes have same color) is **NP** instead of **NP**-complete?

$$\mathrm{3COLOR} = \{\langle G \rangle \mid G \text{ is colorable with 3 colors}\}$$

Comment: It sounds like you want to prove 3COLOR belongs to NP after you have proved it is NP-complete. Is that your intention?

Comment: This seems like a homework question. What have you tried so far? Have your proved 3-Coloring is NP-complete already? To prove it is NP you need a polytime verifier for a certificate of 3-Coloring. Can you think of one?

Comment: Yes, i have already proved it as np complete.

Comment: Yes Apass.Jack that's exactly my intention.

Answer (score 0):

Since **3-Colors** is NP-Complete, it is also in NP.

**Reminder**:

$\bullet$ To prove a problem $P$ is in NP, we have to show a polynomial time "yes" certificate

$\bullet$ To prove a problem $P$ is NP-Complete, we have to show: 
$P \in$ NP *and* there is another problem $X$ which is NP-Complete, and $X$ can be reduced to $P$.

It is clear then, that:

$P$ is NP-Complete $\Rightarrow P\in$ NP.

The first condition is trivial, and the reduction to 3-SAT is widely known and can be found easily.